# 'Request' object has no attribute 'get_json' Werkzeug

Tags: python, json, post, werkzeug

I am unable to print out or read json data from my request.
The POST request is application/json and the json sent is valid.
Any idea why 'get_json' doesn't exist?

```py
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response
import json

@Request.application
def application(request):
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    print(data)
    return Response('Data Received')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
    run_simple('localhost', 5000, application)
```

Replacing `request.get_json` with `request.get_data` returns the json as a string (`d'{\n"example": "here"\n}'`)

I've confirmed my Werkzeug installation is up-to-date.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve my own issue;

`request` doesn't by default have `get_json`, you need to subclass it and add it yourself.

Here's an example:

```
from werkzeug.wrappers import BaseRequest, Response
from werkzeug.wrappers.json import JSONMixin

class Request(BaseRequest, JSONMixin):
    '''Allow get_json with Werkzeug'''
    pass

@Request.application
def application(request):
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    print(data)
    return Response('Data Received')

def __init__(self):
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
            run_simple('localhost', 5000, application)
```